# Going from sub/superscript to regular baseline with keyboard shortcut in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I use mathematical notation a lot. Therefore being able to cntrl+cmd+"+" and cntrl+cmd+- to write super- and subscript is a productivity boon. However, to return to the regular font baseline I need to use the mouse and menubar. Is there a keyboard shortcut that lets me return to using the regular font baseline?

Ps. You can copy some regular text before entering sub/superscript mode and then paste it afterwards to return to regular baseline, however that is a slight hassle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing ⌃⌘+ or ⌃⌘- again seems to remove superscript or subscript in Keynote '09.

Other applications like TextEdit raise or lower the text multiple times though.

You could [give custom shortcuts to nested menu items](https://superuser.com/a/252157/69039) on 10.7, but it stopped working on 10.8.

[image]

Another option would be to create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save a property list like this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict, but it doesn't seem to work in iWork applications.

```
{
    "^@=" = unscript:;
}
```

You could also [assing a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/a/264943/69039) like this:

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
        click menu item "Use Default" of menu 1 of menu item "Baseline" of menu 1 of menu item "Font" of menu "Format" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end try
```